# RestSharp - How to return data from API to View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

```cs
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public double discountPercentage { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public List<string> images { get; set; }
}

public class RootViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel[] Products { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int skip { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class WebProductClient : IWebProductClient
{
    private readonly RestClient _client;
    private readonly string _url;

    public WebProductClient()
    {
        _url = "https://local/host:7123/";
        var options = new RestClientOptions(_url);
        _client = new RestClient(options);
    }

    public async Task<ProductViewModel> GetAllProduct()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("Api/Products");
        var response = await _client.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
        var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductViewModel>(response.Content);
        return r;
    }
}
```

ProductsController:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var all = _client.GetAllProduct();
            
    return View(all);
}
```

Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<DummyShop.Service.ViewModel.ProductViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.discountPercentage)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rating)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.stock)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.brand)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.category)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.thumbnail)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.discountPercentage)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rating)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stock)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.brand)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.category)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.thumbnail)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Returned data from my API:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "iPhone 9",
      "description": "An apple mobile which is nothing like apple",
      "price": 549,
      "discountPercentage": 12.96,
      "rating": 4.69,
      "stock": 94,
      "brand": "Apple",
      "category": "smartphones",
      "thumbnail": "://i.dummyjson./data/products/1/thumbnail./jpg",
      "images": [
        "://i.dummyjson./data/products/1/1./",
        "://i.dummyjson./data/products/1/2./",
        "://i.dummyjson./data/products/1/3./",
        "://i.dummyjson./data/products/1/4./",
        "://i.dummyjson./data/products/1/thumbnail./"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "iPhone X",
      "description": "SIM-Free, Model A19211 6.5-inch Super Retina HD display with OLED technology A12 Bionic chip with ...",
      "price": 899,
      "discountPercentage": 17.94,
      "rating": 4.44,
      "stock": 34,
      "brand": "Apple",
      "category": "smartphones",
      "thumbnail": "://i.dummyjson/data/products/2/thumbnail.",
      "images": [
        "://i.dummyjson/data/products/2/1.",
        "://i.dummyjson/data/products/2/2.",
        "://i.dummyjson/data/products/2/3.",
        "://i.dummyjson/data/products/2/thumbnail."
      ]
    },
      ],
  "total": 100,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 30
}
```

The error I got:

> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DummyShop.Service.ViewModel.ProductViewModel].An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[DummyShop.Service.ViewModel.ProductViewModel,DummyShop.Service.ProductClientsWEB.WebProductClient+d__5]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The attached JSON response is the `RootViewModel` type. You deserialize the `response.Content` as `RootViewModel` type.

```cs
public async Task<RootViewModel> GetAllProduct()
{
    var request = new RestRequest("Api/Products");
    var response = await _client.ExecuteGetAsync(request);
    var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootViewModel>(response.Content);

    return r;
}
```

2. Consider using the `JsonPropertyName` attribute to match the property name in the JSON. Same goes for the other properties, you should name the properties as "Pascal Casing" instead of "camel Case".

```cs
public class RootViewModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("products")]
    public ProductViewModel[] Products { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

3. As in *1* we will return the `RootViewModel` value from the controller, modify the ViewModel as `RootViewModel`. And enumerate with `@Model.Products` for the `<thead>` and `<tr>` elements.

```
@model RootViewModel

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].discountPercentage)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].rating)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].stock)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].brand)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].category)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].thumbnail)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      @foreach (var item in Model.Products) 
      {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            
            <!-- Following td elements -->
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

4. Your controller action should return `Task<IActionResult>` and it is an `async` method.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var all = await _client.GetAllProduct();
        
    return View(all);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your detailed explanation, but when I try this way, I still get the attached error;
--------------------------------


InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[DummyShop.Service.ViewModel.RootViewModel,DummyShop.Service.Product>ClientsWEB.Web__Product5'AllProduct><Geduct'Client] this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'DummyShop.Service.ViewModel.RootViewModel'.

Comment: I got it because I don't use Task in controller, now it's solved thanks I will ask one more question, if you see, can you answer it?

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, I updated my answer with point 4. This will fix the issue as mentioned.